# How to Combine Multiples IPA's file to make single IPA file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios

Is there any way in ios to combine multiple ipa's file and make some installer file i-e (ipa file) so that when installer app installed corresponding apps also installed on iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use App Bundles to sell a set of your apps together

> All members of the Apple Developer Program with paid apps available on
>   the App Store can create app bundles, which are groups of up to 10
>   apps sold together at a reduced price. App bundles can be purchased
>   with a single tap and the individual apps will appear on the
>   customer's device

Check this link for details:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/